# Problem with hiding/revealing input from user on entry using checkbox (TKINTER)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Problem is that when I click on checkbox, entry field does not behave as it should in means of hiding and revealing input.

When in tried to exclude that part of the program, just GUI with buttons and a function to hide/reveal input it works perfectly fine. Obviously, something in this program might be in conflict with the entry, or something else. Do you guys know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from Testing import operater_id, administrator_id
import tkinter.messagebox


def create_second_gui(previous):

    def close_second_gui():
        operater.destroy()
        previous.deiconify()
    
    def check_input_datatype(data):
        try:
            int(data)
            return 1
        except ValueError:
            return 0
   
    def change_operaterid():
        value = entry.get()
        info = check_input_datatype(value)
        if info == 1:
            operater_id = int(value)
            if operater_id == administrator_id:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("", "Succesfully logged as administrator!")
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("", "SUccesfully changed your ID to " + str(value) + "!")
        elif info == 0:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "ID must be number!")
    
    def show_pass():
        if show_password_var.get():
            entry.config(show="$")
        else:
            entry.config(show="")
    
    #Operater GUI code
    operater = tk.Tk()
    operater.title("Operater ID menu")
    operater.geometry("500x500")

    frame = tk.Frame(operater)
    frame.pack(pady=20)


    entry = tk.Entry(frame, show ="")
    entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    show_password_var = tk.BooleanVar()
    show_password_var.set(False)
    show_password_checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(operater, text="Hide ID", variable=show_password_var, command=show_pass)
    show_password_checkbutton.pack(pady=5)

    button = tk.Button(frame, text = "CHange ID", command = change_operaterid)
    button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

    button = tk.Button(operater, text = "Back to ", command = close_second_gui)
    button.pack(pady = 10)
    
    #operater.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    operater.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I can't reproduce the problem (hiding entry working as expected)

Comment: Use `forget` or `enabled` and `disabled`.